# Is there a canon interpretation of who the five are in the Prophecy of the Five from the KOTOR Comics?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

In the *Knights of the Old Republic* comics series, one of the central themes is a Jedi prophecy known as the Prophecy of the Five, which describes five people who are to bring on the return of the Sith and many other horrible things.

[image]
<sub>Knights Of The Old Republic Issue #24</sub>

As the story progresses, everybody offers their own impression of who each of the five are,

> The Covenant Masters justify killing their Padawans because there were five of them, Zayne points out there were five Masters in on the Padawan murders.

When the story arc is resolved with the revelation that

> Haazen is behind everything, he offers his own interpretation, which claims that
>  Zayne is the one for the light, Lucien is the one for the darkness, 
>  Gryph (a criminal choosing to be a good guy) is the darkness standing in the light, Q'Anilia (a blind Miraluka Jedi) is the light standing in the darkness, and lastly
>  Haazen stands apart from them all (as he rejects both Jedi and Sith codes, and has manipulated everyone to serve his own ends).

After this, the final battle goes down,

> the good guys win

and the next story arc doesn't bother to talk about the Prophecy much at all.

So what I'm wondering is if there was ever a definitive interpretation of who the five are, as set down by Lucasfilm, or the authors of the Kotor comics series in an interview or elsewhere. There's so many ways that you can interpret who the prophecy is referring to, and it almost seems like the sort of thing they planned to answer in a later Kotor game or SWTOR, but as it stands, it feels like a loose plot thread. Is Haazen's interpretation the real one, or something the authors had in mind while creating the series, or something else entirely?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Pretty good first question.

Comment: Just a note, that specific text makes no reference to Sith or Jedi, that may have only been projection from the perspective of the Watchers. But also - I believe we see Squint (Malak) wearing a red space suit and some point in the series, and I always took that to be a reference to the fact that Revan and Malak helped bring about the return of the Sith and nearly crumbled the Republic. You could stretch that to the time of the Exile, when the Jedi Order has pretty much faded, and even into the return of the Sith Emperor in SWTOR, and trace it all the way back to the help Squint got from Zayne.

Comment: Just wanted to check, is Knights of the Old Republic part of the Legends canon or the new Disney canon?

Comment: @Gothamite definitely legends now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It was intended to be ambiguous

Here are series writer John Jackson Miller's thoughts on the revelation, from his blog (emphasis added):

> And that brings us to this, the penultimate chapter of “Vindication” — and the bunch of prophecies that it addresses. **Note that I don’t say “resolves” — because I’m more interested in readers knowing what the characters think, and then judging from there to what extent the whole story resolves those prophecies.** But it would be hard to read what I’ve written before about the tensions Force-users face without taking a close look at the Rogue Moon Prophecy itself. A circle of seers, their eyes closed, see danger in a figure — whose defining characteristic is that he cannot see. You can work out quite a lot from there, especially if you can take the step (as they could not) of considering a spacesuit not as a spacesuit — but what it also is: a vessel for something else. Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar — but not this time.
>
> As I said, I’m not going to finish the explanation here — **that’s for the reader to do** — but the story does, through the wildly different figures of Gryph and Krynda, provide counsel on the subject. Sadly, it’s a little too late for the Covenant members!
>
> (source: https://farawaypress.com/comics/starwarsknightsoftheoldrepublic/starwarsknightsoftheoldrepublic34/, original post [archived at Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317035135/http://www.farawaypress.com/comics/swknights/swkotor34.html))

Note that this only directly addresses the Rogue Moon Prophecy, not the Prophecy of the Five, but it seems that it's up to the reader to decide if the given interpretation was right, for both prophecies.

Answer (score -1):

A less helpful response: the *KOTOR* comic series was rendered non-canon *Legends* in 2012, consequently there can currently be no “canon” answer beyond the Prophecy of the Five does not exist in current canon, and so the identities of the non-existent prophecy also don’t exist.

Lucasfilm released a press release identifying the canonical status of the prior published works:
https://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page

This is not to say the prophecy and the characters it might represent will never be canon, as the post-2012 “new” canon has taken Legends elements to recanonize them into the current continuity.